# Could not create an native instance in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: swift, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I am trying to bind native Swift library to my Xamarin IOS project (I use VS on MAC). I followed the guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough
I did everything as mentioned util the "Consume the binding library" step. When I try to create an instance of my ProxyFramework inside my project:
`var proxy = new SwiftFrameworkProxy();`

**I get an error when deploying:**
`Could not create an native instance of the type 'NativeLibrary.SwiftFrameworkProxy': the native class hasn't been loaded.`

I have 3 .xcframework files generated from source repository (I generate them with Carthage), I included all of them in my "NativeReferences". Also I included reference to my ProxyFramework.xcframework to Native references in my Ios Binding Library. In all references I used the following properties (same as in guide):
[.xcframework Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RURkV.png)

My binding library looks like this:
[Ios Binding Library project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98k4B.png)

The only thing I changed in comparison with the guide is I added [Protocol] Attribute to the SwiftFrameworkProxy interface in ApiDefinitions.cs. Without the [Protocol] I got error:
`undefined Objective-C class: SwiftFrameworkProxy. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SwiftFrameworkProxy' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked`
So now the interface looks like:

[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Protocol]
interface SwiftFrameworkProxy

I tried to change LinkWithAttribute params, like ForceLoad, SmartLink, etc, nothing worked